# magento attributes,categories and layered navigation

Tags: magento, configuration, attributes, product, catalog

Attributes for a configurable product don't show in the layered navigation on a category page unless at least one simple product associated with that configurable product is assigned to that category. It seems to me that associated simple products for a configurable product should inherit the configurable products categories as well. As of now I have to go through all the simple products manually and assign categories.

Is this normal behavior in Magento? Do you always have to manually assign categories for simple products under configurable products so their attributes show up in the layered navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have to do this, when you create the child products they should automatically have the same category as the parent product.

Were they created using the quick create feature in the backend?

Comment: Yeh they were. Actually I'm using a third party extension.

Comment: I've tested this out numerous time. If you create a simple product through the quick create, magento does not associate that product with it's parent.

Comment: Ok so, you're right actually. I re-installed a fresh copy of magento and it seems to be working now.

Comment: Maybe your extension had changed/broken the way it works, was it something like Simple Configurable Products extension?

Comment: I think it had to do with store manager for magento software I was using. Everything is working good now so I guess I'm just going to skip using any third party software. Thanks.